# get max value along specific axis with condition in 3d array

Tags: python, numpy

It seems really an issue in python. `np.amax` is also a fast way to get the max value along any axis. Now, I want the same but for values that are not 0 (so, with a condition). So, I need to find the maximum value along an axis if this value is greater or lower than 0.

I did not find anything and np.where is not suitable for a specific axis I find out. And it also very slow.

What is an pythonic and easy and maybe also fast wy to get above problem solved?

Example

```
a= [[[1,0,-3,8],[4,-1,0,-4],[1,-2,-3,8],[4,1,-2,4], [-4,-1,-2,0]],[[3,0, 0,-8],[4,3,2,5],[1,2,3,8],[4,1,2,4], [4,1,2,4]]]
```

I want to get the max value along the last (`axis=2`) axis.

So, above you see the element `[-4,-1,-2,0]`. This would give with `np.amax` just the 0. But in my case I want to ignore all 0's and get in this case the value of -1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use masked array:

```
a = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=a==0)
a.max(2)
```

output:

```
[[8 4 8 4 -1]
 [3 5 8 4 4]]
```

Comment: Okay, question for you. You are using `np.ma.masked_array`, while I was using `np.ma.array`. They both seem to do the same thing when called, at least in this example, although `np.ma.array` is of type function while `np.ma.masked_array` is of type `type`. Is there any practical difference between when you would use one or the other, or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: @alaniwi  I liked your full explanation on your post. They are both essentially the same: from source code: `np.ma.array` is  _Shortcut to MaskedArray._ (a.k.a. `np.ma.masked_array`). source code link: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/ma/core.py#L6549-L6562 Although array has different orders of arguments for backward compatibility. They are both constructors for masked array class and I expect them to work the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a masked array.

**max of numbers < 0**
*(although I now see that this is not a question you were asking - see "update" below)*

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

a = np.array(
    [[[1,0,-3,8], [4,-1,0,-4], [1,-2,-3,8], [4,1,-2,4], [-4,-1,-2,0]],
     [[3,0, 0,-8], [4,3,2,5], [1,2,3,8], [4,1,2,4], [4,1,2,4]]]
)

a_masked = ma.array(a, mask=(a >= 0))  # mask off any values >= 0

print(np.max(a_masked, axis=2))  # max of non-masked values (if any)
```

gives

```
[[-3 -1 -2 -2 -1]
 [-8 -- -- -- --]]
```

**max of numbers > 0** *(likewise)*

To get the maximum of any values >0, you would do same but with values `<=0` masked

```
a_masked = ma.array(a, mask=(a <= 0))
```

This gives:

```
[[8 4 8 4 --]
 [3 5 8 4 4]]
```

which is obviously similar to the maximum without the mask, except that where all values are zero or negative you get a masked value instead of the maximum of the values that exist.

---

### Update

Thank you to Ehsan for pointing out that I have misunderstood the question here. You were asking about maximum of numbers greater than or less than zero -- somehow I misunderstood this as asking two questions:

- maximum of numbers greater than zero
- maximum of numbers less than zero

hence the above

I now understand that you are asking a single question:

- maximum of numbers greater than or less than (i.e. not equal to) zero

Hence of course, just change the mask condition:

```
a_masked = ma.array(a, mask=(a == 0))  # mask off any values == 0
```

gives this time:

```
[[8 4 8 4 -1]
 [3 5 8 4 4]]
```

Comment: You were close. Check out the post above to see how to leverage mask to get all values :)

Comment: @Ehsan Thank you - looks like I misunderstood the question - thought he was asking two questions: max of numbers greater than zero, and then separately max of numbers less than zero. Will edit accordingly.